# Number of variables if some are interpolated

Tags: regression, prediction

Since I didn't found a question close enough to my problem I would very much appreciate your help on the following. (Due to reasons I changed the subject)

Let's say I want to make a prediction on the number of crimes committed per year. I have data for the last 12 years. The problem is now, that since I have for the crimes and some of the independent variables (e.g. average temperature) the monthly values and hence would like to do a monthly model, for others I have only one value per year (e.g. population).

First I simply interpolated*  the yearly ones and did normal regression. But then I started thinking: there are rules of thumb how many times more data you need than variables (I found the numbers 10 to 30 times more and various formulas). I know they are only rules of thumb but let's assume for a moment they are not completely wrong: I have 12 years, i.e. 144 months. Does this mean I should only include one of the yearly variables (since I have only 12 years), but can include several of the monthly ones, or can I "trust" the interpolation (see *) and use them as if they would be also monthly? (Or do I have to take a completely different approach?)

The main reason I ask is that I want to avoid that at the end, someone reads what I have done and simply says "obviously unscientific and hence wrong".

_* I know this is usually not a good idea, but here they are all rather "stable" ones like the population (assume it's not a touristic place with huge seasonal changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two independent variables with different sampling frequencies then when referring to a sampling size you can usually use the higher frequency if both variables are *important* (in some sense) in the model. There's always a room for trickery, of course. For instance, you could add a variable with high frequency which doesn't have any meaningful impact, but you keep it so to prop up the sample size. Just be careful with this aspect, otherwise it's Ok to use higher frequency when referring to a sample size.